# Visual Studio modules load limit?

Tags: visual-studio, module

I noticed a strange issue today with Visual Studio (2010,2012,2013). Some of the modules are missing, not just symbols, but they are not present at all in the Modules window. When I check the count that VC is showing - exactly 500... Is it really possible, VC has a limit and it's so low?

Comment: It is a kernel limitation in XP and Server 2003.  And a registry setting.  Covered by [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953490).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a cap on the number of modules WinDbg can see?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186687/is-there-a-cap-on-the-number-of-modules-windbg-can-see)

Comment: The KB article in question, unfortunately, got deleted somehow. Here's [a link to the Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20100121111745/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953490).

Answer (score 3):

I came across this exact issue today. Visual studios has a hard limit of 500 modules. I am not sure of the reason. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186687/is-there-a-cap-on-the-number-of-modules-windbg-can-see) they describe a way to raise the limit by adding a registry key.

Add this key to your registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager

DWORD DebuggerMaxModuleMsgs = 2048